# Button onclick works when used in webpage but not in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

So I started making a chrome extension, but bumped into a problem rather fast, when I press a button (only element in the popup.html file), it does not run a script that it should, while it does when I run the html file as a webpage.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function mainbuttonpressed() {
        document.getElementById("mainbutton").innerHTML = "B"
        console.log("pressed1")
        alert("You pressed the button!")
        console.log("pressed2")
      }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="mainbutton" type="button" onclick="mainbuttonpressed()">A</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

How does it come that it works when I use it as webpage, but the exact same html doesn't react when used as the default_popup in a chrome extension?

Comment: Try adding an event listener in the script, `document.getElementById("main-button").addEventListener("click", mainbuttonpressed)`

Comment: isn't this an entire different way of detecting the click? I'm wondering why mine doesn't work, not how else I can do it.